# php mysql jquery AJAX autocomplete case sensitivity

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, autosuggest

In my php script,

```
$names = $_GET['part'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  namestable where names LIKE'%$names%' LIMIT 10");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $colors[]=$row['publishers'];
}
```

checks for matches and works well.

But suppose my table has a name Alfred, the suggestion will appear only if i type `Alfr` and not appearing if i type `alfr`

Answer (score 1):

The example you've provided will work if you're using a case insensitive collation such as `utf8_general_ci`. (See the MySQL [Character Set Support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset.html) manual section for more information.)

Alternatively, you could simply use the [LOWER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) function as follows:

```
$names = strtolower(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['part']));
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM namestable WHERE names LIKE LOWER('%$names%') LIMIT 10");
```

Incidentally, if you're attempting to catch differences beyond simple case changes, you could also use MySQL's [SOUNDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex) function to obtain and find a match for strings that sound similar.

Incidentally, you need to use mysql_real_escape_string on your $names variable, or (better still) use prepared statements via the mysqli or PDO interfaces.

Comment: so can u suggest me the corrections i have to make in the code??

Comment: it is saying in the documentation that in soundex `All nonalphabetic characters in str are ignored.` I want to include numbers too..

Comment: @blasteralfred I've updated my answer with a simple solution. As I've said soundex if only if you want to compare similar sounding words - the other solutions I've mentioned would be more appropriate.

Comment: not working.. i think i have to spend a lot with my code ... :(