# How to define custom sort function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, sorting, autocomplete

I use atocomplete.jquery plugin to suggest input text, as the result I get this array:

```
['White 023','White','White flower', 'Teatr']
```

When I start to search something thats begin from `te` substring it shows me array sorting like this:

```
'White','White 023','White flower', 'Teatr'
```

I need something like this:

```
 'Teatr','White','White 023','White flower'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can find some useful answers to this topic here: **[Sorting objects in an array by a field value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26759350/2247494)**

Answer (score 123, accepted):

It could be that the plugin is case-sensitive. Try inputting `Te` instead of `te`. You can probably have your results setup to not be case-sensitive. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985026/php-mysql-jquery-ajax-autocomplete-case-sensitivity) might help.

For a custom sort function on an `Array`, you can use any JavaScript function and pass it as parameter to an `Array`'s `sort()` method like this:

```js
var array = ['White 023', 'White', 'White flower', 'Teatr'];

array.sort(function(x, y) {
  if (x < y) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (x > y) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
});

// Teatr White White 023 White flower
document.write(array);
```

[More Info here on
   Array.sort.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Now i need sorting use this cases:

Comment: Custom sort() calls are useful, but this example is misleading. The comparison function should not return a boolean, but rather a signed integer where a negative return value means x < y, positive means x > y and 0 means x = 0. For example, if x and y were integers, it would be easy to write such a function as function(x, y) { return x - y; }

Comment: You are right Tyler! When i saw the accepted solution i wanted to comment correction but you did it first.

Comment: @Tyler I think you mean that a return value of 0 means x=y, not x=0.

Comment: @abw333 Yes! That was a typo. Too bad I can't edit that comment anymore.

Comment: You can find some useful answers to this topic here: **[Sorting objects in an array by a field value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26759350/2247494)**

Comment: Agh! I just spent 10 minutes trying to figure out why my sort didn't work. Can we fix this typo? It must rank high on google for me to have found it.

Comment: This answer should really be changed or downvoted more as it has misled me multiple times when implementing custom sorts and not getting what I expect, and apparently there are a lot of other people experiencing the same problem (41 upvotes on Tyler's comment as of 6/13/18)

Answer (score 30):

For `Objects` try this:

```
function sortBy(field) {
  return function(a, b) {
    if (a[field] > b[field]) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a[field] < b[field]) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  };
}
```

Comment: Reverses the order.

Answer (score 23):

or shorter

```js
function sortBy(field) {
  return function(a, b) {
    return (a[field] > b[field]) - (a[field] < b[field])
  };
}

let myArray = [
    {tabid: 6237, url: 'https://reddit.com/r/znation'},
    {tabid: 8430, url: 'https://reddit.com/r/soccer'},
    {tabid: 1400, url: 'https://reddit.com/r/askreddit'},
    {tabid: 3620, url: 'https://reddit.com/r/tacobell'},
    {tabid: 5753, url: 'https://reddit.com/r/reddevils'},
]

myArray.sort(sortBy('url'));
console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: `return function(a,b) { return (a[field] > b[field]) - (a[field] < b[field]); }` is what I'm guessing you meant. Clever. Usage example would cinch this, e.g. `my_array.sort(sortBy('my_field'));`

Comment: I like the arithmetic operation. Looks tidier than explicit checks/returns.

Answer (score 1):

```
function msort(arr){
    for(var i =0;i<arr.length;i++){
        for(var j= i+1;j<arr.length;j++){
            if(arr[i]>arr[j]){
                var swap = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
return arr;
}
```

Comment: Default sort in javascript will be much faster than bubble sort. OP is asking for a custom comparator, not a custom implementation of sorting in js.

Comment: When OP explicit said he wants a custom comparator inside the sort function?