# How use natural sorting in array of strings?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have the following array and sort result:

```
['53-15-9', '53-15-10', '53-15-8'].sort() // => ["53-15-10", "53-15-8", "53-15-9"]
```

but I need to get the following result:

```
["53-15-8", "53-15-9", "53-15-10"];
```

How could I get desired result?

Comment: Convert them to numbers for the purposes of comparision

Comment: [How to define custom sort function in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5002848/104380)

Comment: you should check @Maxali's answer. Doesn't say much, but it's exactly what you need.
Also - learn how to provide your own comparison function to sort. Check out the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To compare numbers instead of strings, first remove `'-'`. When you use arithmetic
operation, JavaScript first coverts it to numbers.

`'53-15-9'.replace(/-/g,'')` gives `'53159'`. You can use closures in `sort()` to pass compare function that can simply subtract a from b. The following function will sort the array ascending:

```js
    ['53-15-9', '53-15-10', '53-15-8'].sort(function(a,b){
        return a.replace(/-/g,'') - b.replace(/-/g,'')
    })
```

### Update

As mentioned in the comments, `'54-1-1'` is less than `'53-15-9'`. We can change `'54-1-1'` to `'54-01-01'`. This only works in double digits. We can do it like:

```
function customSort(myArray) {
    myArray = myArray.map(function(a,b){
        var ar = a.split('-');

        return ar.map(function(arK, arV){return (arK<10)?'0'+arK : arK.toString();}).join('-');;
    })

    return myArray.sort(function(a,b){
        return a.replace(/-/g,'') - b.replace(/-/g,'')
    });  
}

customSort(['54-1-2','53-15-9', '53-15-10', '53-15-8']);
// => ["53-15-08", "53-15-09", "53-15-10", "54-01-02"]
```

Comment: And without regex: `return a.split('-').join('') - b.split('-').join('')`

Comment: But if you add `54-1-1` it will be sorted at the beginning, and probably should be at the end.

Comment: @Oriol because its converting to numbers. and 5,411 is smaller than 531,519. \

Comment: @Maxali I know why. I was only noting this may be undesired.

Comment: @Oriol I updated to achieve this sort. Check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom function for splitting and sorting the parts.

```js
var array = ['53-15-9', '53-15-10', '53-15-8'];
array.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aa = a.split('-'),
        bb = b.split('-'),
        i, r = 0, l = Math.max(aa.length, bb.length);
    for (i = 0; !r && i < l; i++) {
        r = (aa[i] || 0) - (bb[i] || 0);
    }
    return r;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your own custom sorting function. Here is an example:

```
['53-15-9', '53-15-10', '53-15-8','2', '53-14-4','53-15-99'].sort(function(a,b){ // a and b are elements of the array
  // split by - and convert values to number 
  a = a.split('-').map(function(val){return Number(val)}) 
  b = b.split('-').map(function(val){return Number(val)})

  // if one has less elements than another, we consider it should go first
  if(a.length != b.length) return a.length > b.length

  //else, one goes after another if one of its elements is greater than the others at that index
  return a.some(function(val, index){
      return val > b[index]
  }) == 0 ? -1 : 1   

})

//output: ["2", "53-14-4", "53-15-8", "53-15-9", "53-15-10", "53-15-99"]
```

Comment: Note you are returning booleans instead of numbers. `false` will be treated as `0`, which means both values should be considered equal. I can't find any counterexample, but I'm not sure this is completely well-defined. If it isn't, the result of the sort will be implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

```
['53-15-9', '53-15-10', '53-15-8'].sort(function(a, b) {
  var aNum = parseInt(a.replace(/-/g, ''));
  var bNum = parseInt(b.replace(/-/g, ''));
  return aNum < bNum ? -1 : aNum > bNum ? 1 : 0;
});
```

Assuming you want to sort them in numerical order including all the sections, simply remove the `-`, parse them as an int and then sort the ints in a custom sort function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = ['53-15-9', '53-15-10', '53-15-8'];
arr.sort(function(a,b){ return a.replace(/-/g,'') - b.replace(/-/g,'') });  
console.log(arr);
```

output

```
["53-15-8", "53-15-9", "53-15-10"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing every number separated by `-` using `Array.prototype.every()`

```js
var arr = ["53-15-8", "53-15-9", "53-15-10"];

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  var curr = a.split(/-/).map(Number);
  var next = b.split(/-/).map(Number);
  return curr.every(function(val, key) {return val <= next[key]}) ? a : b
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
```

Comment: `['1', '2']` is sorted as `['2', '1']`

Comment: @Oriol Yes, updating currently. `.every()` not returning expected results. Approach is to compare each number separated by "-"

Comment: @Oriol See updated post. Adjusted comparison operator to `<=` within `.every()`

Comment: Now `['1-2', '2-1']` is sorted as `['2-1', '1-2']`.

Comment: @Oriol See updated post. Substituted returning `a` , `b` for `-1`, `1`