# Looking for a way to sort an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, lodash

so I have a JSON array that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    row: [
      {
        boat: {
          description: 'Books',
          version: '2',
          id: 6
        },
        airplanes: [
          {
            airplane: [
              {
                description: 'DVD',
                version: 2,
                uid: 69,
                wid: 65,
                id: 84
              }
            ],
            trains: {
              train: [
                {
                  description: 'Pictures',
                  version: 2,
                  id: 149
                }
              ],
              actions: [
                {
                  description: 'This is a really long sentence.',
                  version: 2,
                  tid: 69.01,
                  id: 452
                },
                {
                  description: 'article 2',
                  version: 2,
                  tid: 69.02,
                  id: 453
                },
                {
                  description: 'developer 1',
                  version: 2,
                  tid: 69.03,
                  id: 454
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            airplane: [
              {
                description: 'Games',
                version: 2,
                uid: 65,
                wid: 61,
                id: 80
              }
            ],
            trains: {
              train: [
                {
                  description: 'another great descriptions.',
                  version: 2,
                  id: 145
                }
              ],
              actions: [
                {
                  description: 'being indecisive is good.',
                  version: 2,
                  tid: 65.01,
                  id: 442
                },
                {
                  description: 'couches are comfortable',
                  version: 2,
                  tid: 65.02,
                  id: 443
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am trying to sort the above output by 'wid' in ascending order but still be able to preserve the overall order. For example in the above the wid in element 0 of the array is 65, and element 1 of the array the wid value is 61. Therefore, element 1 and element 0 should be swapped. Is there any built in javascript method to sort json like this?

I will have a json array output a lot larger than the provided example.

Comment: FYI, what you have there is an array of objects, not JSON. [JSON](http://www.json.org/) is a specified data format.

Comment: There is no built in method for such a specific scenario. You will have to write the logic yourself. Or maybe [lodash](https://lodash.com/) may have some method that could help you. Don't know, I don't use lodash.

Comment: There's no built in way, but you can set create a custom sort function in JavaScript and use it on the array of objects (perhaps the `airplanes` array) you're looking to sort within the object. Here's an example of custom sorting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002848/how-to-define-custom-sort-function-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Underscore and LoDash have a sort method that will do what you're looking for. In this example I am assuming that you have the data structure you showed stored in a variable called `data`.

```
 _.each(data, function(obj) {
     _.each(obj.row, function(row) {
        // note the reassignment, _.sortBy does not sort in-place
        row.airplanes = _.sortBy(row.airplanes, function(airplane) {
           return airplane.wid; // This will sort ascending. 
                                // To sort descending, simply multiply by -1
        });
     });
 });
```

So what is this doing? It's taking each array element in your root data structure and looping over it (that's the first `_.each`). Then in each of those objects, it is looping over each `row` element and sorting `row.airplanes` array by the `wid` element contained in each.

Hopefully this helps you. As an aside, that data you posted is strictly invalid JSON. Each key should be double quoted, i.e., `"row"`, instead of just `row` and single quotes are invalid for delimiting strings, i.e., `"DVD"` instead of `'DVD'`. Also, your `boat` version is a string whereas your other version identifiers are integers, it's a good idea to try and keep your version identifiers as integers.

Comment: I tried what you suggested at https://jsfiddle.net/z50rc770/ for some reason, it is not sorting the returned results (see the console output). I did a console.log(row.airplanes); was that not what I was supposed to do? I assumed row.airplanes would return the proper output? or would it automatically update the "data" array?

Comment: I figured out my problem, I was adding both lodash.js and underscore.js cdns into my jsfiddle. Based on your answer, I thought I would have needed both. After realizing it's one or the other. I removed underscore.js and changed the _.each to _.forEach and now it appears to work as expected. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @adbarads Edited answer to make that clearer, thanks

Comment: @adbarads Also, many lodash functions have aliases (to provide drop-in replacement functionality for Underscore.js) so _.each and _.forEach are the same function. https://lodash.com/docs#forEach

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the excellent [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) commandline JSON processor. Extremely fast since it was written in portable C. Easy to understand [documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual).

```
cat <file.json> | jq . -S
```