# Write sorting for date and name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, columnsorting, tablesort

How to write sorting for date and name in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)? I have one table. There are 2 columns: `name` and `created date`:

```
name:  ["A", "A9", "A10", "A11", "A3"]
createdDate: ["Apr 2, 2019 3:07 PM", "Apr 10, 2019 9:25 AM", "Apr 30, 2019 6:08 PM", "Apr 10, 2019 8:25 AM", "Apr 2, 2019 8:07 PM"]
```

I already try using sort method. Output should like this:

```
name: ["A", "A3", "A9", "A10", "A11"]
createdDate: ["Apr 2, 2019 3:07 PM", "Apr 2, 2019 8:07 PM","Apr 10, 2019 8:25 AM", "Apr 10, 2019 9:25 AM", "Apr 30, 2019 6:08 PM"]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define custom sort function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002848/how-to-define-custom-sort-function-in-javascript)

Comment: Actually its not working for alphanumeric character. i already try by below code :-

.sort(a,b){

var firstEl = (a === undefined) ? a :a.toUpperCase();
var secondEl = (b === undefined) ? b: b.toUpperCase();
if(firstEl === undefined || firstEl === "") {return (1)}
if(secondEl === undefined || secondEl === "") {return (-1)}
if(firstEl === secondEl) {return 0;}
return firstEl < secondEl ? (-1) : (1 );
}

Comment: should the sorting of `name` affect `createdDate` and vice versa?

Comment: Yes its should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can sort the `name` array alphanumerically, using localeCompare(), and passing numeric as one of the options.

```js
const name =  ["A", "A9", "A10", "A11", "A3"];
name.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, 'en', { numeric: true }));
console.log(name);
```

Here is how you can sort them by dates. Essentially, we convert them to JavaScript date objects when doing the comparison.

```js
const createdDate = ["Apr 2, 2019 3:07 PM", "Apr 2, 2019 8:07 PM","Apr 10, 2019 8:25 AM", "Apr 10, 2019 9:25 AM", "Apr 30, 2019 6:08 PM"];
createdDate.sort((a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b));
console.log(createdDate);
```

Comment: but i do have combination of  string and alphanumeric character and its not working

Comment: Just to check, did you try the above method with that name array you specified? `["A", "A9", "A10", "A11", "A3"]`? Because when I tested it out locally, it gives me this `["A", "A3", "A9", "A10", "A11"]`, which is actually correct?

Comment: yeah! already tried but i have new test case like name contain :-
name: ["a", "a10", "a11", "A9", "Atlas", "btlas"]

is this case its not working

Comment: now i have added condition for alphanumeric character but i have one doubt is above method always working fine for date ?

Comment: @kashifazmi I have updated my answer to check for sorting of dates. Do try it out? :)

Answer (score 0):

To sort strings :

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
    var titleA = a.title.toLowerCase(), titleB = b.title.toLowerCase();
    if (titleA < titleB) return -1;
    if (titleA > titleB) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

To sort dates :

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
    var dateA = new Date(a.release), dateB = new Date(b.release);
    return dateA - dateB;
});
```

Refer to this document https://en.proft.me/2015/11/14/sorting-array-objects-number-string-date-javascrip/ for more details.

Answer (score 0):

to do it properly I'd combine the answers of [sudip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55946799/4304864) and [wentjun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55946817/4304864)

strings:

```
name.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, 'en', { numeric: true }));
```

dates:

```
createdDate.sort((a, b) => Date.parse(a) - Date.parse(b));
```