# Trying to sort array without sort() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```
// sorting an array

const least_num = (arr)=>{
  let smallest = arr[0];
  let smallest_index = 0;
  for(let i=1; i<arr.length;i++){
    if (arr[i] < smallest) {
      smallest = arr[i];
      smallest_index = i;
    }
  }
  return smallest_index
}


const sortArray = (arr)=>{
 const newArr = [];
 for(let i in arr){
  let smallest = least_num(arr);
  console.log(smallest,i)
  console.log(arr.splice(smallest,1),arr)
 }
 return newArr;

}

console.log(sortArray([5,4,3,2,1]));
```

I am trying to sort array without sort().
It stuck at array length of 2.
It may because of for loop. And how to remove element in a array using index.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002848/how-to-define-custom-sort-function-in-javascript can help you?

Comment: `arr` is modified during the `for` loop because of [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). Try with `slice` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues:

- The code never adds anything to `newArr`, so the function always returns an empty array. It should add the removed (spliced) element to `newArr`. This can be done with `newArr.push(...arr.splice(smallest,1))`
- The `for..in` loop will iterate fewer times than expected, because in each iteration the array gets shorter, thereby removing future iterations for the loop. As the idea is to remove *all* items from the array, just keep looping until the array is empty with `while (arr.length)`

With these two corrections, your code works:

```js
const least_num = (arr)=>{
  let smallest = arr[0];
  let smallest_index = 0;
  for(let i=1; i<arr.length;i++){
    if (arr[i] < smallest) {
      smallest = arr[i];
      smallest_index = i;
    }
  }
  return smallest_index
}


const sortArray = (arr)=>{
    const newArr = [];
    while(arr.length) {
        let smallest = least_num(arr);
        console.log(smallest)
        newArr.push(...arr.splice(smallest,1));
        console.log(arr)
    }
    return newArr;
}

console.log(sortArray([5,4,3,2,1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can also try this.**

```
const sortArray = (arr)=>{
    let originalArr = [...arr];
    var sortArr = [];
    while(originalArr.length) {
        let val = originalArr[0];
        for ( let j = 1; j < originalArr.length; j++ ) {
            if(val>originalArr[j]) {
                val = originalArr[j];
            }
        }
        sortArr.push(originalArr.splice(originalArr.indexOf(val), 1)[0]);
    }
    return sortArr;
}
console.log(sortArray([5,4,3,2,1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to sort the array in ascending and descending order

```js
 function sortGivenArray(arr, order) {
  let temp;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if ((order === "asc" && arr[i] > arr[j]) || (order === "dsc" && arr[i] < arr[j])) {
        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(sortGivenArray([6, 4, 8, 2, 10, 30, 31], "asc"));
console.log(sortGivenArray([6, 4, 8, 2, 10, 30, 31], "dsc"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sort function using selection sort algorithm.

```js
const selectionSort = (arr) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        let smallest_index = i;
        for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[j] < arr[smallest_index]) {
                smallest_index = j;
            }
        }
        if (smallest_index !== i) {
            // Swap elements if necessary
            [arr[i], arr[smallest_index]] = [arr[smallest_index], arr[i]];
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(selectionSort([5, 4, 3, 2, 1]));
```